# Logistic regression visualization

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm learning basic machine learning models and stuck with the next problem: the predicted line doesn't fit well with the dataset. I'm generating a simple 2 class dataset and training SVM and logistic regression. While the metrics show good results, the visualisation is poor: the trained line clearly doesn't separate two classes. I don't quite understand what's wrong, can somebody explain it?

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=2, n_features=2, center_box=(0, 12))

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

plt.plot(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 0] * svc.coef_[:, 1] + svc.coef_[:, 0])
plt.plot(X_train[:, 0][y_train == 0], X_train[:, 1][y_train == 0], 'g^')
plt.plot(X_train[:, 0][y_train == 1], X_train[:, 1][y_train == 1], 'bs')
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly your problem is. Please, explain it in more detail. e.g., what you have tried so far, what you have observed and etc.

Comment: In addition, please make your code reproducible - where do `X_train` and `y_train` come from, and how exactly "*the metrics show good results*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the error, though it's a little hard to be certain because the code you demonstrated is incomplete, and you confuse between logistic regression and SVM. To clarify, I will answer for logistic regression.  With that in mind, the formula you use to plot the decision boundary is wrong.

The formula for logistic regression is:

[image]

We define the decision boundary as the values of x_1 and x_2 such that h(x) is 0. So then rewrite the equation in terms of one of the input variables.

[image]

So then just to implement this into the code.

```
# Gather model parameters
theta_0, theta_1, theta_2 = clf.intercept_[0], clf.coef_[:, 0], clf.coef_[:, 1]

# Choose a pair of x values that fit nicely with your data
x_vals = [np.min(X_train[:, 0]) - 2, np.max(X_train[:, 0]) + 2]

# Apply the formula
y_vals = [- (theta_0 + theta_1 * x)/theta_2 for x in v_vals]

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '--', c='r')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I now understand where I went wrong! And yes, I've confused the code with SVM because I was trying different models.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that helps! :-)